# Как в рамкак одного соединения посылать множество GET запросов?

Tags: java, парсер

Открываю соединение вот так:
`HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) startUrl.openConnection();`

Этому соединению присваивается `sessionID` и токен (токен уникален для каждой сессии). С этого соединения я получаю необходимые данные для конструирования GET запроса, но если снова использовать `.openConnection();` для GET запроса, то это будет уже другая сессия и другой токен.

Comment: Вы неправильно ставите вопрос. На самом деле, вас должно интересовать, как сохранить значение sessionID и токен между запросами. Для этого нужно настроить CookieManager. Краткий тьюториал по теме на сайте Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/cookies/index.html

Comment: @PakUula Буду изучать спасибо. Вы имеете ввиду, что я при каждом запросе должен передавать куки с токеном ?

Comment: Если вы правильно настроите менеджер кукесов, то при каждом обращении java.net.http будет отправлять sessionID и токет, сохраненные в ваших кукесах.